# Differences between forced early binding methods (In CPython) and how to access values stored in function?

Tags: python, cpython

Using the CPython implementation of Python 3.9.16 consider the following codes

```py
def foo_a():
    x = 1
    fun = (lambda _x: lambda: print(_x))(x)
    x = 2
    return fun

def foo_b():
    x = 1
    fun = lambda _x=x: print(_x)
    x = 2
    return fun

fa = foo_a()
fb = foo_b()
```

where I've used two different methods for forcing early binding of `x`. I believe these are semantically equivalent, however I notice that the resulting functions have different closures.

```py
print(fa.__closure__)    # (<cell at 0x0000025CED84BFD0: int object at 0x0000025CE9E36930>,)
print(fb.__closure__)    # None
```

In the case of `fa` I can access the local `_x` variable using `fa.__closure__[0].cell_contents`, but where is the local `_x` stored in `fb` if not inside its closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, `_x` is a free variable whose value is found in a non-local scope carried by the inner function via a closure. (Informally, we say the inner function closes over the variable `_x` in the outer function.)

In your second example, `_x` is a local variable assigned at call time by an argument to `fun`, or if none is provided, from a default value stored in the function itself.

Your *use* of both functions is the same, but if you received a reference to the inner function in the first example, it would be "harder" to change the value of `_x` (you'd have to poke around in the closure itself; closures are, for better or worse, mutable) than it would be to change the value of `_x` in the second example (you would just pass a different argument).